# Converting UTC-Date-String to Unixtimestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a date formated like this: `"2018-06-12T13:58:36.663550655Z"`

I want be convert this string into a Unix time stamp.

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
    date = '2018-06-12T14:03:35.306662173Z'
    time = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    unixTime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time)
```

When i run it, there's a error:

> ValueError: time data '2018-06-12T14:03:35.306662173Z' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

Would be nice if someone could help me !
Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `datetime.strptime()` returns a `datetime` object, not a posix timestamp.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think you need `time = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z")` to take care of the timezone identifier

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping the extra info.

**Ex:**

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
date = '2018-06-12T14:03:35.306662173Z'
d = datetime.strptime(date[:26],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
unixTime =  time.mktime(d.timetuple())
print(unixTime)
```

**Output:**

```
1528792415.0
```